# For d3js, has anybody created a mapping of types of input data to possible types of output charts?

Tags: charts, d3.js

Is there already a way to automatically generate possible samples of a d3js output graph based on the nature of the input?

I'm trying to tabulate different charts on the d3js gallery page [d3js gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) to the nature of input data.  i.e. if there were two columns of data and one of them is a number, then we could generate a bar graph or a line graph.

Eg.
Bar Graph; {columns:2, yaxis: number, xaxis: number/date/nominal} 
[SpeedoMeter](http://bl.ocks.org/metormote/6392996); single number value

At least has somebody already got a start on this?

Comment: I don't know of any attempt to organize d3 examples by input data types,but there are certainly many such organizational systems for data visualization in general.  http://guides.library.duke.edu/vis_types  http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Graphical-Analytic-Techniques

Comment: I have thought that the d3 wiki gallery could use some clean up, and grouping examples by type of input data would be one option.  But it gets complicated: some visualizations can be adapted easily for continuous versus categorical data, others not at all.  However, even if you did tag every example by what type of data it could take, that doesn't mean you could switch between them at a click.  That's where the chart libraries like NVD3 are useful; they all have a standard input format, so it is easy to switch options.

Answer (score 0):

No. This would be a huge amount of work because you can make many types of graphs work with many kinds of data. The closest there is would probably be [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/), which allows you to create graphs from pre-defined data structures with a few lines of code.